# Datapicker com @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho a seguinte model

```
    [DisplayName("Data Inicial Contrato")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DataInicialContrato { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data Final Contrato")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DataFinalContato { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @for = "datainicialcontrato" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", @id = "datainicialcontrato"  } })
                <span class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFinalContato , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @for = "datafinalcontrato" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFinalContato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "datafinalcontrato" } })
                <span class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFinalContato, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</span>
            </div>

 </div>
```

O datapicker não está aparecendo. Preciso que apareça um datapicker com formato DD/MM/YYYY e esteja em português.

Comment: Não aparece nada? Como fica o HTML gerado? Apenas copiei o seu código [para este exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcwTdB) e funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar o [DatePicker Bootstrap](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @for = "datainicialcontrato" })
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @id = "datainicialcontrato"  } })
     <span class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicialContrato, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</span>
</div>
```

E no `javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```